# jQuery blur() on Chrome not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, blur

I'm on MacOSX running this http://jsfiddle.net/q84wv/ on `Chrome` latest version.

It won't work, while running that on Firefox it works perfectly, any clue?

Comment: Its working, try pressing `tab` key ;)

Comment: @AkhilSekharan i can't hope all website users holding tab key, probably 90% of users don't uses tab key :P so i need to get it to work without extra actions hope my english it's ok

Comment: May be you meant a 1mouseout` event

Comment: @AkhilSekharan nope mouseout !== unfocus :P

Comment: But it's not an input element, is it? That's just an anchor.

Comment: What do you expect to happen? When the user's mouse leaves the element, the alert should trigger?

Comment: @BenM exactly, when the element losts focus -> alert()

Comment: but in Firefox it works perfectly

Comment: @BenM yeah, you catched dude, just waiting little time to accept your answer! thanks a lot

Comment: is my answer good enough to accept?

Comment: @MohammadMasoudian sure if i could accept multiple answers :P the BenM answer shows a really awesome trick, so i don't need to trigger focus first :P

Comment: anyway +1 to all the answers by my side!

Comment: @sbaaaang listenting to both `mouseup blur` event's will bring alert box twice, but MohammadMasoudian's answer works fine, check in mozilla where blur is working

Comment: @AkhilSekharan in my case it works like a charm and mouseup fixes the blur not fired problem on chrome, i can't ask more really

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming that you want the `alert()` to be triggered either when the user tabs out from the anchor, or completes a click event, this should work:

```
$('.menu a').on('blur mouseup',function(){
    alert('oh');
});
```

Check this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q84wv/8/).

It really depends what you're classing as `blur` here. If you're wanting it to trigger whenever the user's mouse leaves the element, you can use `mouseleave` instead:

```
$('.menu a').on('blur mouseleave',function(){
    alert('oh');
});
```

Comment: But would't it fire twice, in some cases. May be just mouse up is enough

Comment: Give an example of when this would fire twice please

Comment: @AkhilSekharan: No, because the OP wants to use `mouseleave` (see the comments), which doesn't trigger `blur` in FF.

Comment: Oh. but I thought he doesn't want to use mouseout/mouseleave check the comments in the question

Comment: The method is irrelevant. I think his comment was that he didn't want to *exclusively* use `mouseout` / `mouseleave`. Either way, it looks like the OP is happy.

Comment: yeah as i sad i can't image better trick than this and it works with no problems

Answer (score 7):

you must first **focus** then **blur**

```
$('.menu a').click(function() {
  $(this).focus();
});

$('.menu a').on('blur',function(){
    alert('oh');
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q84wv/10/)

Comment: I think this answers the question ;)

Comment: @MohammadMasoudian +1 the BenM answer is just little bit better trick

Answer (score 2):

Well for that first you have to apply `blur` and blur the menu out.

```
$('.menu a').click(function() {
  $('.menu a').blur();
});

$('.menu a').on('blur',function(){
    alert('oh');

  });
```

You were trying to alert if that menu has been blurred. But you were not blurring it. That's why it was not working.

FIddle : http://jsfiddle.net/q84wv/4/

Now click on the menu item(s) and you will find the alert coming up .