# Javascript. Chrome doesnt trigger the blur() function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, google-chrome

```
$this->_editModeAlertSyntax = 
  "onfocus=\"try{if (__isEditMode){alert('Not able to edit.');window.blur()}}catch(exp){}\"";
```

This code works well in IE and Firefox, but for Chrome it doesn't work as what it supposed. I suspect that the chrome doesn't trigger the `blur()` function.

Are there any other alternatives?

Comment: format your code please

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery blur() on Chrome not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18250120/jquery-blur-on-chrome-not-working)